# Diagnosing Head Gasket Leak: Coolant bubbles, but doesn't squirt

Tags: head-gasket, coolant-leak

According [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCo0SLeMEfk&t=1352s) when the coolant squirts, while the cap is of and the engine is running, this is an indication for a leaking head gasket.

I have tried this method on my car and have somewhat different results. Bubbles are forming, but there is no squirting. Is this a clear cut case of a faulty head gasket, or are the bubbles not enough?

I also have other symptoms, like oily coolant, losing coolant.

This is what it looks like on my car: [video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/9jt3uZeyFhKqaXky7)

Comment: You can check for exhaust gases in the radiator, this is a sure sign the head gasket is blown....https://www.amazon.com/Lisle-75500-Combustion-Leak-Detector/dp/B0007ZDRUI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bubbles can usually be an indicator. Coupled with the oily coolant and coolant loss, it seems like a pretty cut and dry case. However the only way to know 100% is to get your exhaust tested or system pressure tested at a shop.

My money is on a blown head gasket though. Keep an eye on your oil and engine temp and get it checked soon.

Comment: Thanks. I was at 2 shops, who said they were going to test everything, but they didn't mention the head gasket at all. One replaced the cap, the other is tipping on the radiator hoses, which are kind of stiff. One of the shops was even a licensed shop for my brand. So I am not very confident in the shops right now, I would rather try to diagnose myself. I know I can do a HC test on the cooling with a kit, which I will probably do, how should I approach testing the exhaust? System pressure test at the shop showed no leakage.

Comment: @user1721135 I’ve never tested it myself and it may be anecdotal but the pressure test gave a false negative for me and a combustion test at my mechanic showed true positive a couple months later.

Comment: I have the exact problem and the exact scenario with 3 mechanics :). 
Small leak (1.5 litre on 1000km). tight hoses, pressure test ok, only get small bubbles on the coolant reservoir only on hot engine. One of them suggested head gasket an another one said I can leave with that. I've never experienced high temperature above normal. what did you mechanics suggested?

Comment: @emirjonb After testing positive with the combustion test, my mechanic replaced the head gasket because it was causing my Honda to overheat on long drives.